# Java AffineTransform view changes

Tags: java, graphics2d, affinetransform

I am attempting to plot a simple graph and use the following code to manage the graph coordinate system:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

// Save the current transform to put it back the way I found it
saveAT = g2d.getTransform();

int height = getHeight();
// Get the get the magnitude of the sample
long scale = thePlotArray.getRealScale();

// Set the x origin at 0 and the y origin in the center of the window
double yTrans = ((double)height)/2.0;
AffineTransform tform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance( 0.0, yTrans);

// set the y scale to show all of the sample
double yScale = ((double)height) / ((double)scale);
tform.scale(1, yScale);
g2d.setTransform(tform);

// Plot the data with a series of 
g2d.drawLine(x1,  y1, x2, y2);

// reset the transform back
g2d.setTransform(saveAT);
```

It seems to work well until I resize the window and then the origin jumps up about 1/10th of the window.  The numbers all seem to be the same when I print out the height, scale, yTrans, etc.

Is there something I am not doing?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue (for a simple bar graph).  The painting method is:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(_data==null){
        return;
    }

    int bars = _data.length;
    int width = this.getSize().width/bars;
    int height = this.getSize().height;

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    AffineTransform flip = new AffineTransform();
    flip.translate(0, height);
    flip.scale(1, -1);
    g2d.setTransform(flip);

    //Painting code via g2d.drawRect(), g2d.fillRect()
```

}

My display panels are embedded in another panel.  Whenever display.componentResized() is called is appears to cause the origin to translate up about 24 points.  I have this as part of a MVC demo, and for some events that generate repaint (with or without adjusting the values in the display), the origin appears to be properly reset to (0,0).

Further troubleshooting reveals that the error is only present when this display panel is present within a JTabbedPane.  As an example, adding a MouseListener to repaint the display on the mouseMoved() action resolved the origin.

Switching between tabs restores the issue.  Attempting to repaint the display as part of handling the ChangeEvent had no effect.

No resolution as of yet.